# How to get alerts from action in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, controller, alert

as far as I know we can not call the javascript method in controller's action method. but how to consider that a particular code line get executed ? As i asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676783/asp-net-mvc-application-not-running-after-deployment) 
we must have to get acknowledgment that line number so and so get executed. see this action in my controller

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult uploadfile(FormCollection fc)
        {
            UserMaster objUMaster = objAM.GetUser(new Guid(fc["userIdForFile"].ToString()));
            try
            {

                string imagename = "";
                //Check for files uploaded here.
                foreach (string inputTagName in Request.Files)
                {

                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[inputTagName];
                    imagename = objUMaster.UserId.ToString() + file.FileName;
                    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Content/UserUploads"), objUMaster.UserId.ToString() + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                        file.SaveAs(filePath);

                        string filePathThumb = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Content/UserUploads/Thumbnails"), objUMaster.UserId.ToString() + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

                        var fl = Request.Files.Get(inputTagName);
                        Stream strm = fl.InputStream;
                        Image img = Image.FromStream(strm);

                        ResizeAndSaveHighQualityImage(img, 120, 120, filePathThumb, 100);


                    }

                }
                objUMaster.ProfilePhoto = imagename;
                objAM.Save();



                return RedirectToAction("EditProfile", new { id = objUMaster.UserId });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //SendEmail(ex.Message);

                string strPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Content/UserUploads");

                StreamWriter SW;
                SW = System.IO.File.CreateText(strPath+"/log.txt");
                SW.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());             
                SW.Close();

                return RedirectToAction("EditProfile", new { id = objUMaster.UserId });
            }
        }
```

Here I am trying to upload the image in my domains file system (dir). but I want get alert so that I can confirm , this lie get executed successfully. because nothing happening as expected from this action. so can we call Javascript's "alert", or something else remedy?

Comment: Expecting some help please ..... :(

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers to help you:

- See if Network service/account under which your application is running has permission on the location where you are saving your file.

Besides this to make sure that your file is saved, after save call you can make another call File.IsExist. If it exists then you can log the success/failure in some log file. Wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: Thanks pradeep, I'll definitely try this and get back to you.

Comment: Pradeep i tried this but couldn't solve this issue. but temporary i keep send mail function with specified string values as per line. it is bit unprofessional, so good enough for testing published solution. and i think i have track the issue. just read my new question here :                                                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690055/unable-to-call-action-from-view-int-his-way-in-asp-net-mvc