# Unable to call action from view int his way in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, post, action

I am developing the image upload module for my asp.net mvc application. for that I write code partially in my view page as

```
//Other html code...
 <div id="popuup_div" class="popup_msg">
  <form action="/UserProfile/uploadfile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <%= Html.Hidden("userIdForFile",Model.UserId) %>
   <p>
     <label for="ProfilePhoto"><%= Resources.Global.ProfilePhoto %>:</label>
     <input type="file" name="pPhoto"  />
   </p>
   <input type="submit" value="upload" /> |<input type="button" value="close" onclick="javascript:$('#popuup_div').hide();" />    
  </form>
</div>

//Other html code...
```

But unable to call the action after code get published . why should be this . can somebody help me ?

**Edited:**

```
     <% using (Html.BeginForm("uploadfile", "UserProfile", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "testform", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
             {%>
            <%= Html.Hidden("userIdForFile", Model.UserId)%>
           <p>
             <label for="ProfilePhoto"><%= Resources.Global.ProfilePhoto%>:</label>
             <input type="file" name="pPhoto"  />
           </p>
           <input type="submit" value="upload" /> |<input type="button" value="close" onclick="javascript:$('#popuup_div').hide();" />    
 <% } %>


    **Edited**
```

In firebug i got this text of my HTML with light colored :[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that when you publish the site there is a virtual directory involved. So `/UserProfile/uploadfile` is no longer a correct url. To avoid this you should never hardcode your urls like this. I would recommend you using HTML helpers.

So:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("uploadfile", "UserProfile", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```

Comment: I agree: You should use <% Using Html.BeginForm() %> <% End Using %> so the MVC-engine will render automatically the action-url to the form-tag. If even this does not help you should check whether the action inside the controller accepts POST-parameters (<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)>)

Comment: Thanks guys , I tried this remedy , but somehow it still not posting data to controller. I checked that , controller is there, its action is also there, even locally it is running perfect (with yours code also) but after published it this is not working. please help....

Comment: Are you getting an error? What happens when you submit the form? What is the file size you are trying to upload?

Comment: @Lalit, I see where the problem is. You have missed an argument in your `BeginForm` method. Just before `FormMethod.Post` there is `null` which corresponds to `routeData`. Look carefully at my example.

Comment: @ Darin , thanks again, I tried with null but not get more sweet here ... :) .. Sorry to say but i could not track any exception or error still. but in firebug, i caught the html code. please see the image in edited question, I found that the problematic part of code rendering some html but firebug is showing it in light color than other code line. this means there should be some issue to process this code. can you please tell me what should its meaning ?

Comment: It seems that you have two nested forms which is not allowed.

Comment: Yes i am using, you are right. i am using as Beginform1...end form 1... Begin form 2... end form 2. this was there earlier, and was running perfect. but why can not now?